# Generate password with alpha numeric characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, alphanumeric

I want to generate a random password with Alpha numeric characters in it. I have written a function which returns a random password with Alpha-numeric characters. But i only want to add 4 alphanumeric characters from the provided string.
**Edited**: I know this is not the best solution, but i have managed to get the desired output, If someone would like to get his hands on the code and optimize it, then it would be really helpful.

```js
function getRandomPassword(length, numberOfNonAlphaNumericChars) {
const passwordDigit = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP1234567890";
const alphaNumericChar = "!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:>|./?";
var temp1 = "";
var temp2 = "";
var pass = "";
if(length < 1 || length > 128) {
console.log("Number Exceeds");
}
if(numberOfNonAlphaNumericChars > length || numberOfNonAlphaNumericChars < 0) {
console.log("Error");
}
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    temp1 += passwordDigit.charAt(x);
    }
  for(var j = 0; j < numberOfNonAlphaNumericChars; j++) {
    var alphaNumericCharPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfNonAlphaNumericChars);
    temp2 += alphaNumericChar.charAt(alphaNumericCharPos);
  }
    
  var newPass = [temp1.slice(0, x), temp2, temp1.slice(x)].join('');
    
  console.log(newPass);
  return newPass;
}
getRandomPassword(16, 4);
```

jsfiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/37rjgfad/11/)

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that calls the code, and what you expect it to return ? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand this requirement: "But i only want to add 4 alphanumeric characters from the provided string." In your example you're asking for 16 characters: do you mean you want at least 12 of them to be not alphanumeric, i.e. from your symbols string? What about `randomString(16, '#aA')` where you don't want symbols at all?

Comment: You can see the snippet on jsfiddle. Currently it is returning a 16 digit random password. But i only want 4 alphanumeric characters to be included in the password
eg: abcAbCdEkJpT$*^&

Comment: Your example abcAbCdEkJpT$*^& has 12 alphanumeric characters and 4 symbols (alphanumeric = letters and numbers). Did you mean 4 non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @Rup. I wanted only 4 alphanumeric characters to be present in the password.

Comment: So are you OK with less than 4 alphanumeric characters, or do they have to be exactly 4?

Comment: This would probably not be the cleanest way to do this but maybe the easiest way based on the code you already have: Generate your password like you already do but without the special chars then pick 4 random special chars and insert them at random locations in your string (replacing the old value to not increase string length).

Comment: @Chaz I have edited the code, I know thats not the best solution, but little optimization in it would really help

Comment: Since you're not initialising x outside the loop this will put all four symbol characters at the start of the string, and you only support putting the four of them next to each other.

Comment: @Rup Yes, i am finding ways to put the 4 alphanumeric character at random position..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you exactly 4 *non*-alphanumeric characters:

```js
function jumble(str) {
  return [...str]
    .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    .join('')
}

// no change to this function
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var mask = '';
    if (chars.indexOf('a') > -1) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
    if (chars.indexOf('!') > -1) mask += '!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:>|./?';
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += mask[Math.round(Math.random() * (mask.length - 1))];
    return result;
}

console.log(
  jumble(randomString(12, 'aA#') + randomString(4, '!'))
)
```

Modify as needed if you want a different distribution. For example:

```js
jumble(
  randomString(4, 'a')
  + randomString(4, 'A')
  + randomString(4, '!')
  + randomString(4, '#')
)
```

Would give you a 16-character string containing exactly 4 of each character type, or:

```js
jumble(randomString(12, '!') + randomString(4, 'aA#'))
```

Would give you 12 non-alphanumerics and 4 alphanumerics.

Comment: Would love to know why this was downvoted, given that it answers the question exactly as per OP's example?

Comment: I have updated the question, the code is not the best solution, but have brought to a state to get the desired output. If you can help in optimizing the code then it would be really helpful.

Comment: Still not clear what you want. You want the 4 non-alphanumerics to always appear next to each other? Also, what needs "optimizing" about your code?

Comment: I want only 4 alphanumeric characters to be present in the string at random position.

Comment: Based on that description, this answer already solves your problem.

Comment: Instead of using one more function jumble(). can we return the same thing in the randomString function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221109/discussion-between-lionel-rowe-and-tkamath99).

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce the alphanumeric string from which you select the characters to 4 characters only.

```js
function randomString(length, chars) {
  var mask = '', result = '';
  if (chars.indexOf('a') > -1) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    result += mask[Math.floor(Math.random() * mask.length)];
  }
  mask = '';
  if (chars.indexOf('!') > -1) {
    mask += '!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:>|./?';
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < length - 4; i++) {
    result += mask[Math.floor(Math.random() * mask.length)];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(randomString(16, 'aA#!'));
console.log(randomString(16, '#aA'));
console.log(randomString(16, '#A!'));
```

The second call to the function returns an undefined result after the first 4 characters since the password is limited to 4 alphanumeric characters, and symbols are not allowed.

Note that by calling `document.write()` you are first erasing the document, then appending the new text. You will only be able to see the text you last written. Hence, I've used `console.log()`.

Comment: Alphanumeric covers all of abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ and 0123456789, not just the lower case set. And I don't think the requirement is 'distinct characters'. But in any case I think the actual requirement is 'at most 4 non-alphanumeric characters' from OP's example in the comments.

Comment: This was not for what i had asked. This is actually replacing the 4th index with the alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Then what exactly do you want?

Comment: @WaisKamal I have updated the question, the code is not the best solution, but have brought to a state to get the desired output. If you can help in optimizing the code then it would be really helpful.

Comment: This is *exactly* what you ask for in the question: only 4 alphanumeric characters in the password.